# CUDA7.5+VS2012Pro+Nsight5.0のデバッグが止まらない

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

VS2012ProにNsight5.0をインストールして新規プロジェクトを作成しました。
NVIDIA > CUDA 7.5 > CUDA 7.5 Runtime

デフォルトで作成されるサンプルプログラムのカーネルの中にブレイクポイントを設定し、Start CUDA Debuggingを実行してもブレイクポイントで止まりません。

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i]; // <ここにブレークポイントを設定
}
```

なにか設定が足りてないのでしょうか？

Comment: `addKernel` 関数が実行されていない(呼びだされていない)のではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
表示結果をみると関数は正常に呼びだされているようです。

Comment: [Troubleshooting](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/ParallelNsight/1.51/UserGuide/HTML/Troubleshooting.html) に「I am unable to set and hit a breakpoint in my CUDA code.」という項目があって、こちらが参考になるかもしれせん。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。情報のご提供ありがとうございます。調べてみます。

Comment: @argus
その後、色々と試してみましたが、全く止まる気配がありません。
試しに別のPCに同様の環境を構築してみたところ、こちらでは何の問題もなくデバッグできることを確認しました。今後はこちらのPCで開発を進めたいと思います。
今回のケースはPC固有の問題なのかもしれません。